# Why is beatboxing called 「ヒューマンビートボックス」?

Tags: katakana, loanwords

I was watching TV when the topic turned to certain celebrities' ability to beatbox. In talking about this every mention of the term beatbox was

> **ヒューマン**ビートボックス.

Why is **human** necessary?
The use of katakana is only natural, but why take a relatively long katakana word and make it longer with a completely unnecessary word?

**Note**
After going through the links in the answers and comments, I realized it was using ヒューマンビートボックス like this: `俺、ヒューマンビートボックスできるよ！` in English `I can human beatbox!` that made me think it strange.

Comment: There's also  ボイパ（ボイスパーカッション）

Comment: Probably the want to distinguish electronic drum machine and humans' imitating drum machine.

Comment: Never heard a drum machine called a beatbox. A drum machine is a machine beatboxing is done by a person is the only way I had ever heard these terms used.

Comment: I am not sure if a drum machine called a beatbox actually exists or not though, "beatbox" sounds like referring to percussion called "[Cajon](https://www.kopfpercussion.com/blog/the-cajon-the-history-of-the-beatbox-drum/)". Anyway, I understand why you are wondering.

Comment: As a non native English speaker, i can イメージ a Beatbox as a device ("a box that beats").

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The term is a loanword from the English term *human beatbox* or *beat box*: a person that makes musical sounds using the human vocal organs. The abbreviated term is *beatbox* or *beat box*. The performer is also called a human beatboxer or simply a beat boxer. The word *human* was retained in the term to enable understanding of its usage within specialized communities and to differentiate its use from the sounds made by machines.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatboxing#Contribution_to_hip-hop):

> The term "beatboxing" is derived from the mimicry of early drum machines, then known as beatboxes, particularly the Roland TR-808. The term "beatbox" was used to refer to earlier Roland drum machines such as the TR-55 and CR-78 in the 1970s. They were followed by the TR-808, released in 1980, which became central to hip hop music and electronic dance music. It is the TR-808 that human beatboxing is largely modeled after.

Comment: Yeah, [*human beatbox*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doug_E._Fresh) is the original term, so I think it got borrowed into Japanese in its long form.  So rather than *adding* a word, they simply haven't *lost* the word like we did in English.

Comment: （〇_〇） I'll never assume anything again for the rest of my life... Seeing the origin, it makes sense that human was used (in English), but I never would have imagined that the "human" part would have remained in use for any amount of time.

Comment: The two terms are still used in English to differentiate how the sound is being made.